# Change an image after some time

Tags: css

I currently have this code in my css file that contains the image that will be displayed on the about page. Is there a way of setting multiple images and having a timer that can let the images change after a period of time?

```
.aboutHero {
    background-image" url("./images/palm1.jpg);
    min-height: 60vh;
}
```

Comment: I think you can't achieve this with CSS alone , you have to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: As @2pha showed in his answer making an infinite cycle through all images is possible. With JS you can make this go through randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.image-fader {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-fader img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  animation-name: imagefade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}

@keyframes imagefade {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

.image-fader img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.image-fader img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.image-fader img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.image-fader img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-fader">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/f00/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/0f0/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/00f/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/f0f/fff" />
</div>
```

Comment: Was just gonna post my Answer using JS, but only CSS is way more nice :)

Comment: In the above example, there isn't any transparency in any of these images. I tried to do this using a set of SVG images. On page load, all of the images could be seen stacked on top of one another. Then the animation plays and one by one, the images fade out and in order, once everyone has got their first run. To fix the issue with the initial load stack being visible, we can add `opacity: 0;` to the `.image-fader img` selector. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting a simple timer that changes the src of the image after a certain amount of ms. Here is an example:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <img class="image" src=""/>
          <script>
               $( document ).ready(function(){
                    let images = [
                         "image 1",
                         "image 2",
                         "image 3",
                    ];
                    var i = 0;
                    window.setInterval(function(){
                         $('.image'). attr("src", images[i]);
                         i = (i==images.length-1) ? 0 : i+1;
                    }, 5000);
               });
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Note that this is written using JQuery so you may need to change the code a little depending on the framework you are using, but the logic is the same.